# Java Client receives error from .NET WCF Service - HTTP Status Code 415

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

There's a .NET WCF Service and I have a Java consumer client.

While sending a request I get a response with an error:-

```
Invoking handleMessage... Sending Message to server... Exception in
thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException:
    The server sent HTTP status code 415: Cannot process the message 
    because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset="utf-8";
    action="http://tempuri.org/IServiceBus/HandleMessage"' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:196)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:168)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
```

What would I implement so as the client-server interaction work?

Any advice is GREATLY appreciated.

I also have a JaxB binding file but not sure what changes I need to make into it.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type. You're getting this because you are sending **soap+xml** while the server expects **soap+msbin1**. msbin1 looks to be some wcf binary type, to which you'll probably have to find out how to encode your request.

Comment: Thanks @CeilingGecko, yes right, but how would you advice me to implement the changes. I am just doing a unit testing using a main method. I am passing an object with all the request detail hard coded. And I have a JaxB binding file.

Comment: Still ceased with the problem. Any suggestion please?